# Replacing native VS 2010 (VC10) tr1 libraries with Boost.TR1

Tags: c++, boost, replace, tr1, vc10

I have been using VS 2005 (VC8) with Boost.TR1 in the std::tr1 namespace by setting the Include Directories of VS to prioritize the boost tr1 headers as described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_tr1/usage.html#boost_tr1.usage.native).

Now I am moving over to VS 2010 (VC10) and I seem to be getting compilation errors using the same include method.

The Include Directories are set to:

1. [boost-root]\boost\tr1\tr1
2. [boost-root]
3. VC standard include directories

Sample code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
 std::cout << std::tr1::bind(std::minus<int>(), 5, std::tr1::placeholders::_1)(5)
  << std::endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Build output:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: test_tr1, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Build started 17/8/2010 1:01:58 PM.
1>_PrepareForClean:
1>  Deleting file "Release\test_tr1.lastbuildstate".
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "Release\test_tr1.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>ClCompile:
1>  main.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(26): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(27) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::tr1::_Unrefwrap<_Type>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(26): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(26): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(84): error C2039: '_Remove_reference' : is not a member of 'std::tr1'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(84): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(84): error C2433: '_Remove_reference' : 'inline' not permitted on data declarations
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(84): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(84): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(84): error C2059: syntax error : '<'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(84): error C2039: '_Type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(92): error C2039: '_Remove_reference' : is not a member of 'std::tr1'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(92): error C2039: '_Type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(94): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(94): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(139): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(168) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(139): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(139): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(140): error C2059: syntax error : '<'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(140): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(142): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_Ty1x'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(142): error C2535: 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::_Pair_base(void)' : member function already defined or declared
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(124) : see declaration of 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::_Pair_base'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(148): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(148): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(153): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_Ty1x'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(153): error C2535: 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::_Pair_base(void)' : member function already defined or declared
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(124) : see declaration of 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::_Pair_base'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(221): error C2059: syntax error : '<'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(273) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(221): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(222): error C2059: syntax error : '<'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(222): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(224): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_Ty1x'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(224): error C2535: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair(void)' : member function already defined or declared
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(181) : see declaration of 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(230): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(230): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(236): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_Ty1x'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(236): error C2535: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair(void)' : member function already defined or declared
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/utility(181) : see declaration of 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xutility(282): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xutility(284) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Is_checked_helper<_Iter>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xutility(500): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xutility(504) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Ptr_cat_helper<_Elem,_Elem>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xutility(500): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xutility(503): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(345): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(345): error C2433: 'enable_if' : 'inline' not permitted on data declarations
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(345): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(345): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(345): error C2059: syntax error : '<'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(345): error C2039: 'value' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(346): error C2065: '_Ret' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(347): error C2065: '_Rx' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(348): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '__cdecl'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(348): error C3861: '_Rx': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(349): error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(360): error C2065: '_Rx' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(361): error C2065: '_Rx' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(362): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '__cdecl'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(362): error C3861: '_Rx': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(364): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(365): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '__cdecl'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(365): error C3861: '_Rx': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(366): error C2065: '_Callable' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(367): error C2065: '_Rx' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(367): error C2065: '_Rx' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(367): error C2065: '_MyBind' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(368): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(374): error C2947: expecting '>' to terminate template-argument-list, found '>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(375): error C2039: 'value' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(375): error C2065: 'value' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(375): error C2275: 'std::tr1::_Rx' : illegal use of this type as an expression
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(374) : see declaration of 'std::tr1::_Rx'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(376): error C2065: '_Ret' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(379): error C2947: expecting '>' to terminate template-argument-list, found '>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(379): error C2974: 'std::tr1::_Callable_fun' : invalid template argument for '_Ty', type expected
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xrefwrap(185) : see declaration of 'std::tr1::_Callable_fun'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(379): error C2975: 'std::tr1::_Callable_fun' : invalid template argument for '_Indirect', expected compile-time constant expression
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xrefwrap(185) : see declaration of 'std::tr1::_Callable_fun'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(380): error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::_Callable_fun'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xrefwrap(185) : see declaration of 'std::tr1::_Callable_fun'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(380): error C2065: 'type' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(380): error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'bind'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(380): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '__stdcall'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(380): error C2514: 'std::tr1::_Rx' : class has no constructors
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(374) : see declaration of 'std::tr1::_Rx'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(381): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(383): error C2065: '_Callable' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(384): error C2065: '_Ret' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(384): error C2065: '_MyBind' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(385): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(394): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(396): error C2065: '_Callable' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(397): error C2065: '_MyBind' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(398): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(404): error C2947: expecting '>' to terminate template-argument-list, found '>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(405): error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'enable_if'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(405): error C2065: 'is_same' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(405): error C2065: '_Ret' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(405): error C2039: 'value' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::_Bind'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/functional(380) : see declaration of 'std::tr1::_Bind'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(406): error C2065: '_Ret' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(409): error C2955: 'std::tr1::_Bind' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\../include/functional(380) : see declaration of 'std::tr1::_Bind'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(410): error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(410): error C2065: 'type' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(410): error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'bind'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(410): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '__fastcall'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(410): error C2514: 'std::tr1::_Rx' : class has no constructors
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(374) : see declaration of 'std::tr1::_Rx'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(410): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(411): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(413): error C2065: '_Callable' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(414): error C2065: '_Ret' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(414): error C2065: '_MyBind' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(415): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(424): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(426): error C2065: '_Callable' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(427): error C2065: '_MyBind' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(428): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(240): error C2906: 'std::tr1::_Binder<false,1>' : explicit specialization requires 'template <>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(257): error C2947: expecting '>' to terminate template-argument-list, found '>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxbind1(257): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.48
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

It seems like it is using VC10's tr1 headers instead of boost. What is the correct method to get VS to use Boost.TR1 as a replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining `_HAS_CPP0X=0` in the project's set of defines - that's supposed to disable VC10's TR1 support.

Comment: but won't that remove other c++0x features (like &&) as well?

Comment: @Tobias: I don't think so - I'd imagine that the macro wouldn't affect actual language support features, only exclude things from headers. But I can't claim to have experience with using the macro, so testing of this suggestion would certainly be in order. As far as I know, this isn't a documented 'configuration setting' by MS - right now it's just a bit of lore from the headers and various C++ forums.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft advises [against using `_HAS_CPP0X=0` with VS2010](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/622227/vs2010-c-cli-linker-problem-duplicate-types-lnk2022-metadata-operation-failed). What you can do is:

1. Use Microsoft's tr1 implementation (not recommended, it's buggy)
2. Use the boost tr1 features directly from the boost namespace using full qualifiers (e.g. `boost::function(..)`, `boost::bind(...)`, etc.). You get name clashes otherwise.
3. Use [using-declarations](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522404/share-ptr)