# What differences, if any, between C++03 and C++11 can be detected at run-time?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++03, language-detection

It is possible to write a function, which, when compiled with a C compiler will return 0, and when compiled with a C++ compiler, will return 1 (the trivial sulution with 
`#ifdef __cplusplus` is not interesting).

For example:

```
int isCPP()
{
    return sizeof(char) == sizeof 'c';
}
```

Of course, the above will work only if `sizeof (char)` isn't the same as `sizeof (int)`

Another, more portable solution is something like this:

```
int isCPP()
{
    typedef int T;
    {
       struct T 
       {
           int a[2];
       };
       return sizeof(T) == sizeof(struct T);
    }
}
```

I am not sure if the examples are 100% correct, but you get the idea. I believe there are other ways to write the same function too.

What differences, if any, between C++03 and C++11 can be detected at run-time? In other words, is it possible to write a similar function which would return a boolean value indicating whether it is compiled by a conforming C++03 compiler or a C++11 compiler?

```
bool isCpp11()
{ 
    //???
}
```

Comment: Related: [Incompatibilities between ISO C and ISO C++](http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm) (no mention of C++0x, unfortunately)

Comment: Another Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399615/what-breaking-changes-are-introduced-in-c11 (What breaking changes are introduced in C++11?).

Comment: And what's the point of this exercise? Firstly, you do have a macro, and secondly it will take a number of years before compilers start implementing all features of C++0x, in the meanwhile it will be a mix. So the only reasonable test is the compiler a version macro.

Comment: This fits the bill of not a real question but it seems too interesting to follow the rules!

Comment: @Gene et al: Do you downvote all questions which are interesting but you don't see the pragmatic "point"?

Comment: "We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise". I think this question meets these expectations, vote for reopen.

Comment: @six if you look around, many valid questions on SO challenge "folks to write a block of code". Still that doesn't make it codegolf and doesn't make it offtopic. You have it wrong.

Comment: @six This can't objectively have a winner. And has a fixed limit of valid answers (there is only a fixed variety of incompatibilities introduced). Two things that codegolf questions don't share with it.

Comment: @six: It **can** and does have correct answers. But not **one** correct answer, rather a limited set of correct answers

Comment: @six: That's not true at all. This is a legitimate C++ question which is asking whether it is possible to exploit incompatibility between C++03 and C++0x. But I guess reasoning isn't something that's gonna convince you, so... let's agree to differ here

Comment: @sixlettervariables: while it's certainly open to argument that the phrasing could be better, it seems to me that the fundamental notion of the question (what differences, if any, between C++03 and C++0x can be detected at run-time?) is perfectly legitimate. Given that the code has to compile and execute in both, it could also be phrased as being about the breaking changes in C++0x. That seems to me like a perfectly legitimate question to ask as well.

Comment: @DanMoulding: That's because, as you could have guessed, the purpose of the question is more about code that works differently in C++11 and C++03 rather than a practical way to detect the compiler version. Duh

Comment: @DanMoulding: There was a HUGE debate as to how to word the question. This even migrated to codegolf and back and was discussed at meta. This wording seems to be the consensus the community arrived at

Answer (score 108, accepted):

#### Core Language

Accessing an enumerator using `::`:

```
template<int> struct int_ { };

template<typename T> bool isCpp0xImpl(int_<T::X>*) { return true; }
template<typename T> bool isCpp0xImpl(...) { return false; }

enum A { X };
bool isCpp0x() {
  return isCpp0xImpl<A>(0);
}
```

You can also abuse the new keywords

```
struct a { };
struct b { a a1, a2; };

struct c : a {
  static b constexpr (a());
};

bool isCpp0x() {
  return (sizeof c::a()) == sizeof(b);
}
```

Also, the fact that string literals do not anymore convert to `char*`

```
bool isCpp0xImpl(...) { return true; }
bool isCpp0xImpl(char*) { return false; }

bool isCpp0x() { return isCpp0xImpl(""); }
```

I don't know how likely you are to have this working on a real implementation though. One that exploits `auto`

```
struct x { x(int z = 0):z(z) { } int z; } y(1);

bool isCpp0x() {
  auto x(y);
  return (y.z == 1);
}
```

The following is based on the fact that `operator int&&` is a conversion function to `int&&` in C++0x, and a conversion to `int` followed by logical-and in C++03

```
struct Y { bool x1, x2; };

struct A {
  operator int();
  template<typename T> operator T();
  bool operator+();
} a;

Y operator+(bool, A);

bool isCpp0x() {
  return sizeof(&A::operator int&& +a) == sizeof(Y);
}
```

That test-case doesn't work for C++0x in GCC (looks like a bug) and doesn't work in C++03 mode for clang. [A clang PR has been filed](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=10196).

The [modified treatment of injected class names](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=9551) of templates in C++11:

```
template<typename T>
bool g(long) { return false; }

template<template<typename> class>
bool g(int) { return true; }

template<typename T>
struct A {
  static bool doIt() {
    return g<A>(0);
  }
};

bool isCpp0x() {
  return A<void>::doIt();
}
```

---

A couple of "detect whether this is C++03 or C++0x" can be used to demonstrate breaking changes. The following is a tweaked testcase, which initially was used to demonstrate such a change, but now is used to test for C++0x or C++03.

```
struct X { };
struct Y { X x1, x2; };

struct A { static X B(int); };
typedef A B;

struct C : A {
  using ::B::B; // (inheriting constructor in c++0x)
  static Y B(...);
};

bool isCpp0x() { return (sizeof C::B(0)) == sizeof(Y); }
```

---

#### Standard Library

Detecting the lack of `operator void*` in C++0x' `std::basic_ios`

```
struct E { E(std::ostream &) { } };

template<typename T>
bool isCpp0xImpl(E, T) { return true; }
bool isCpp0xImpl(void*, int) { return false; }

bool isCpp0x() {
  return isCpp0xImpl(std::cout, 0);
}
```

Comment: Nice. I can confirm that this solution works here with g++ (GCC) 4.6.0, both with and without -std=c++0x.

Comment: This returns `true` for MSVC 2005 onwards, and a compile error in MSVC 2003.

Comment: Oh dear, they broke backwards compatibility!

Comment: Both of the tricks used can return `true` prematurely with compiler extensions

Comment: The `constexpr` test is invalid C++0x, since the function is not defined. The `enum` test returns `false` for MSVC 2010 --- I guess it's not "C++0x"-y enough :-) Nice idea though.

Comment: @Anthony, hmm, the spec allows `constexpr` on function declarations (and has examples for it). I thought that calling such a non-defined declaration just means that the call is not a constant expression (as it matches one of the bullets in 5.19 - "an invocation of an undefined constexpr function or an undeﬁned constexpr constructor"). Is there a rule I missed? It works on GCC.

Comment: @Johannes: Sorry, my mistake. I forgot that got changed. It works OK in g++ 4.6, but g++ 4.5 complains.

Comment: Removed the local classes thing because it's not valid C++03 SFINAE :(

Comment: @Johannes : This is the most fun you've had in weeks, isn't it? ;-]

Comment: I find these very all interesting, but I think the most clever is the `(...)` vs `(char*)` calls. I really like that!

Answer (score 44):

I got an inspiration from *[What breaking changes are introduced in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399615/what-breaking-changes-are-introduced-in-c11)*:

```
#define u8 "abc"

bool isCpp0x() {
   const std::string s = u8"def"; // Previously "abcdef", now "def"
   return s == "def";
}
```

This is based on the new string literals that take precedence over macro expansion.

Comment: +1: Very interesting, indeed, but technically breaks the requirement of not using the preprocessor. But the restriction was not intended to dismiss such nice answers :)

Comment: Yeah, the preprocessor is a bit hacky considering the question. But I couldn't resist :)

Comment: Well, if you follow the function with a `#undef u8` then the preprocessor usage is only observable if your program has a previously-defined macro named `u8` (boooo).  If that is a real concern, that can still be worked around using implementation-specific push/pop macro pragmas/calls (most implementations have these, I believe).

Comment: One fairly reasonable argument is that on a C++03 system someone might #define u8 to provide simulated C++0x capabilities. Still, I really like the answer.

Comment: you can just move this isCpp0x function to a separate translation unit so this macro thing won't affect other code.

Comment: I think there's a difference between using the preprocessor to rely on the compiler setting some macro value, and using the preprocessor to detect actual language features. That's why I don't think that this answer is cheating.

Answer (score 33):

How about a check using the new rules for `>>` closing templates:

```
#include <iostream>

const unsigned reallyIsCpp0x=1;
const unsigned isNotCpp0x=0;

template<unsigned>
struct isCpp0xImpl2
{
    typedef unsigned isNotCpp0x;
};

template<typename>
struct isCpp0xImpl
{
    static unsigned const reallyIsCpp0x=0x8000;
    static unsigned const isNotCpp0x=0;
};

bool isCpp0x() {
    unsigned const dummy=0x8000;
    return isCpp0xImpl<isCpp0xImpl2<dummy>>::reallyIsCpp0x > ::isNotCpp0x>::isNotCpp0x;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<isCpp0x()<<std::endl;
}
```

Alternatively a quick check for `std::move`:

```
struct any
{
    template<typename T>
    any(T const&)
    {}
};

int move(any)
{
    return 42;
}

bool is_int(int const&)
{
    return true;
}

bool is_int(any)
{
    return false;
}


bool isCpp0x() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    return !is_int(move(v));
}
```

Comment: +1 A cool idea indeed :) However, in practice this will break with Visual C++ 2005/2088 which do not support C++0x but allow >> to be used in templates the C++0x way.

Comment: Oooh; I like the ADL abuse!  However, couldn't a conforming C++03 implementation have a function named `std::move`?

Comment: @FredOverflow: I wouldn't bother. The UI sucks!

Answer (score 16):

Unlike prior C++, C++0x allows reference types to be created from reference types if that base reference type is introduced through, for example, a template parameter:

```
template <class T> bool func(T&) {return true; } 
template <class T> bool func(...){return false;} 

bool isCpp0x() 
{
    int v = 1;
    return func<int&>(v); 
}
```

Perfect forwarding comes at the price of breaking backwards compatibility, unfortunately.

Another test could be based on now-allowed local types as template arguments:

```
template <class T> bool cpp0X(T)  {return true;} //cannot be called with local types in C++03
                   bool cpp0X(...){return false;}

bool isCpp0x() 
{
   struct local {} var;
   return cpp0X(var);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have turned that into a trait class ;)

Comment: +1 Nice idea, I'm only not sure if `isC++0x` is a valid C++ identifier ;)

Comment: What's a good reference for the reference from references inference?

Comment: @kerrek-sb: The draft talks about this in 8.3.2.6 (References)

Answer (score 15):

This isn't quite a correct example, but it's an interesting example that can distinguish C vs. C++0x (it's invalid C++03 though):

```
 int IsCxx03()
 {
   auto x = (int *)0;
   return ((int)(x+1) != 1);
}
```

Comment: Technically, this relies on `sizeof(int) != 1` being true.  On an 0x system with exceptionally large `char`s, the results could be the same. Still a neat trick, though.

Comment: @Dennis - `char` is always one byte though

Comment: @Node: one byte is not always 8 bits.

Comment: @Node `sizeof(char)` will always be 1, by definition. But `CHAR_BIT` (defined in limits.h) is allowed to be more than 8. As a result, both `char` and `int` could have 32 bits, in which case `sizeof(int) == 1` (and `CHAR_BIT == 32`).

Answer (score 12):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759232/stdvector-default-construction-c0x-and-breaking-changes):

```
struct T
{
    bool flag;
    T() : flag(false) {}
    T(const T&) : flag(true) {}
};

std::vector<T> test(1);
bool is_cpp0x = !test[0].flag;
```

Comment: I wondered how this could work; having tried it, it's clear now: there's a little bug. it works if you change the last line to: `bool is_cpp0x = !test[0].flag;`

Comment: plausible: C++0x default constructs `T` whereas C++03 copy constructs from `T()`

Answer (score 9):

Though not so concise...
In current C++, class template name itself is interpreted as a type name
(not a template name) in that class template's scope.
On the other hand, class template name can be used as a template name in
C++0x(N3290 14.6.1/1).

```
template< template< class > class > char f( int );
template< class > char (&f(...))[2];

template< class > class A {
  char i[ sizeof f< A >(0) ];
};

bool isCpp0x() {
  return sizeof( A<int> ) == 1;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T> void test(T t) { t.first = false; }

bool isCpp0x()
{
   bool b = true;
   test( std::make_pair<bool&>(b, 0) );
   return b;
}
```

Comment: N.B. technically this tests the standard library not the compiler, and although it is valid C++03 and valid C++0x, it's not valid C++98, so with some tweaks could be made to detect a C++98/C++03/C++0x stdlib