# Why might std::bind1st be considered "almost unusable"?

Tags: c++, boost-bind, std

During a conversation on `boost::bind`, it was noted that `std::bind1st` exists in C++03, but that it is "almost unusable".

I can't find anything solid to back this up.

[The `boost::bind` documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/bind/bind.html) says:

> **boost::bind** is a generalization of the
>   standard functions **std::bind1st** and
>   **std::bind2nd**. It supports arbitrary
>   function objects, functions, function
>   pointers, and member function
>   pointers, and is able to bind any
>   argument to a specific value or route
>   input arguments into arbitrary
>   positions. **bind** does not place any
>   requirements on the function object;
>   in particular, it does not need the
>   **result_type**, **first_argument_type** and
>   **second_argument_type** standard
>   typedefs.

perhaps suggesting that these restrictions *do* apply to `std::bind1st`.

Other than the obvious restriction on number of arguments, what *are* the advantages of `boost::bind` to `std::bind1st`/`std::bind2nd`? Is there any merit to the assertion that `std::bind1st` is "almost unusable" in C++03?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we look at C++03 20.3.6.1 and 20.3.6.2, then we see that for the functor argument to `bind1st` we have a requirement of three `typedef`s (for the result type, first and second argument), and that the resulting operator only takes one argument.

This means that we cannot just use `bind1st` easily on plain function pointers as they do not have those `typedef`s. Also we can only use `bind1st` on binary functions as we have no support for more parameters. Furthermore `boost::bind` *et al* have the advantage of being able to reorder the parameters, and of course support more than just the first.

It seems to me that the most use cases for a binder are for free functions and member functions, and not for functor objects; as such the use of `bind1st` is quite limited (though extensible through the use of other tools like `ptr_fun`, but it's questionable as to whether this makes it more usable). Of course this is only based on personal experience, but someone might want to do a Google code search statistic for `bind1st`.

Comment: Note that `ptr_fun` solves the first problem, by giving you an Adaptable Binary Function that wraps a specified function pointer. Doesn't solve the rest, though. Calling `ptr_fun` is easy, remembering to do so slightly harder ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The function call operator of the type that `bind1st` returns is

```
typename Operation::result_type
operator()(const typename Operation::second_argument_type& x) const;
```

This won't work with reference parameters of the bound function object and a very strict C++03 compiler (more recent releases are more lax). C++03 forbids references to references.

Comment: Shouldn't the references collapse? I think I read something like that for typedefs, same with `const`.

Comment: @Xeo not in C++03. Some people also use it [to distinguish between C++03 and C++0x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473218/what-differences-if-any-between-c03-and-c0x-can-be-detected-at-run-time/6473994#6473994), although with recent compilers that won't work.