# Ways to distinguish string literal and runtime generated string

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, string-literals

Suppose I have a function that takes a string as input:

```
SomeOutputType f_impl(const char* s);
```

Most call sites just use string literals as input, e.g. `f("Hello, world")`.  Suppose I have implemented the following function to compute the result at compile time

```
template <char...> SomeOutputType f_impl();
```

My question is, is there a way to let the call sites like `f("Hello, world")` calls the templated form, while for general call sites like `string s="Hello, world"; f(s.c_str());` calls the general form?  For clarification, `auto s = "Hello, world"; f(s);` don't have to call the templated form because `s` is now a variable and no longer a compile time constant.

A useful case for this question is to optimize `printf`.  In most cases the `format` will be string literals so a lot of things can be done at compile time to optimize things, instead of parsing the `format` at runtime.

Comment: Your function template has no input argument. Is that intended?

Comment: Yes, the string literals should be converted to the template paramters.

Comment: You can't invoke a function uniformly if you have to supply a *function* argument in one case and a *template* argument in another case

Comment: Well I modified my question so that it reflects my intension clearly.  Users call function `f` and it somehow dispatches to different forms of `f_impl` according to whether the call site uses string literal or not.

Comment: So basically you want to specialise a template on whether a function argument was a string literal?

Comment: @icando I had read your question and I still am interested to know why you need this. I was assuming you're not a standard library implementor and are not writing `printf` yourself.

Comment: @PeterWood, I am actually trying to implement printf (for my own use, not to publish to any standard library).  I want it be type-safe so I uses varadic template, so that I can do type checks.  Also I want to check the `format` string if it is given as a literal.

Answer (score 17):

No, a string literal like `"foo"` has the type `const char[S + 1]` where `S` is the number of characters you wrote. It behaves like an array of that type with no special rules.

In C++03, there was a special rule that said that a string literal could convert to `char*`. That allowed you to say

```
#define isStringLiteral(X) \
  isConvertibleToCharStar(X) && hasTypeConstCharArray(X)
```

For example `isStringLiteral(+"foo")` would yield `false`, and `isStringLiteral("foo")` would yield true. Even this possibiliy would not have allowed you to call a function with a string literal argument and behave differently.

C++11 removed that special conversion rule and string literals behave like any other arrays.  In C++11 as a dirty hack you can compose some macros, matching some simple string literals without handling escape sequences

```
constexpr bool isStringLiteral(const char *x, int n = 0) {
  return *x == '"' ? 
           n == 0 ?
             isStringLiteral(x + 1, n + 1)
             : !*(x + 1) 
           : (*x && n != 0 && isStringLiteral(x + 1, n + 1));
}

#define FastFun(X) \
  (isStringLiteral(#X) ? fConstExpr(X, sizeof(X) - 1) : f(X))
```

Comment: I not only need to know if the input is string literal, but also need to know the content at compile time.

Comment: @icando you can know the contents at compile time. But you cannot know that what was given is a string literal.

Comment: How to know the content at compile time?

Comment: well, looks like you are mislead by my title, I apologize.  I don't just want a function to tell me if something is string literal or not, but I also need to compute something based on the string literal's content at compile.  For example, I want to write a function to compute the sum of all characters in the string literal at compile time.

Comment: @icando i am not mislead, you don't need to worry.

Comment: ok, if you were not mislead, then I have to say your answer is totally useless for my question here.

Comment: @icando don't worry. it may be useful to others.

Comment: Then please delete it, it is totally irrelevant to my question here.

Comment: @icando no, I won't delete it. It correctly explains why it is not possible to do what you asked for. I can understand that you find it frustrating that it won't work, but having no answer instead of an answer that states it doesn't work won't change it.

Comment: `In C++03, there was a special rule that said that a string literal could convert to char*` Erm.. really? I thought that you could initialise a `const char*` or a `char[n]` from a string literal (where `n` may be omitted), but never `char*` to be compliant.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub, you are so wrong.  It is possible.  I actually have a hacky answer in my mind, and I am looking for an elegant way to do it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit surprise! :) It's item #3 in http://stackoverflow.com/a/6473250/34509

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: o.O Then why has GCC _always_ warned that this is non-compliant? _\[edit: correction, [deprecated](http://codepad.org/IFlCyQkm) - guess that explains that\]_

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, your answer doesn't make any sense.  It can't even pass the compile.

Comment: @icando: Johannes Schaub is a world-reknowned _expert_ in C++ who has contributed significant expertise to the standards committee itself, so you might want to spend a little less time blaming everybody for doing everything wrong, and a little more time in trying to figure out what it is that _you_ are doing wrong.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, now I gained more confidence over myself now.  If such a person is a C++ expert, then I can definitely call myself C++ super expert now.  It also explains why C++ is evolving so slowly and losing its popularity.  It is because standard committee is filled by those non-creative guys.  Actually C++ itself is an art, and lots of powerful paradigms are found by programmers, not by the committee guys.

Comment: @icando: Yes, that's exactly right. You are "C++ super expert".

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel, I am not anti-committee, I just want to kick this stupid answer out of my question here.  A guy ``has contributed significant expertise...'' doesn't mean everything he said is correct.  Whether an answer is correct or incorrect is just a matter of fact, irrelevant to who said it, even if he was smart in the past.

Comment: @icando: That is true - there is no direct logical equivalence and one does not prove the other. However, regardless, this answer _is_ correct and there's no way out of that one.

Comment: @icando Absolutely, appealing to authority is a weak argument. How about letting the voters decide?

Comment: @icando It's not stupid if it's the truth, even if said truth is inconvenient for you.

Comment: @icando: You know, you *can* actually operate on a string at compile-time - there's `constexpr`. Doesn't change the fact that you *can not* find out if said string was a literal or not. There is just *no* way in standard C++.

Comment: @icando I am now invoking [Godwin's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godwin's_law). Discussion over; you lost.

Comment: @PeterWood, I never called for discussion.  I was only ASKING questions.  So anyone who is out-of-imagination is out of my consideration.  Win/lose only happens to those guys who are really smart and I consider as rivals.

Comment: I dunno. This guy could be great. He should start a sect. It would be Super Effective

Comment: @sehe: Suddenly, a wild smattering of OMG WTF appears.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't tested this, I think if you just declare the function constexpr and compile with high optimization, the compiler will compute at compile time whenever possible.  As a bonus, you don't need to write the code twice.  On the other hand, you have to write it once in constexpr style.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand the question correctly, I actually think something like this is possible using a function overload.  [Here's an article](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/10/27/quasi-compile-time-string-hashing/) that shows the basic idea.  In your case I think it would be sufficient to have the following two overloads:

```
void f(char const *);

template<unsigned int N>
void f(char const (&)[N]);
```

The latter should be invoked when the string is a string literal, the latter at other times.  If the compiler is sufficiently good at optimizing then calls to the latter may be evaluated at compile time.

EDIT:

Alright, it bothered me that the above solution didn't work, so I did some playing around and I think I came up with a solution:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>

template<typename T>
struct is_string_literal {
  enum { value = false };
};

template<unsigned int N>
struct is_string_literal<char const (&)[N]> {
   enum { value = true };
};

template<typename T>
typename boost::disable_if<is_string_literal<T> >::type
foo(T) {
  std::cout << "foo1" << std::endl;
}

template<int N>
void foo(char const (&)[N]) {
  std::cout << "foo2" << std::endl;
}

int main( ) {
  std::string bar = "blah";
  char const str[] = "blah";

  foo(str);
  foo("blah");

  foo(bar.data());
}
```

The output (on GCC 4.4 with -O3) is:

```
foo2
foo2
foo1
```

I admit that I don't completely understand why this works when the previous solution didn't.  Maybe there's something about overload resolution that I don't completely understand.

Comment: The non-template function is always a better match than template functions (try out the code and see which one is chosen).

Comment: Well, this still relies on the optimization of the compiler and only works for simple `f_impl`.  I don't think for functions as complicated as `printf` this technique helps.

Comment: @Jesse Seems you're right.  It does beg the question of how the author got the results he did in the post.

Comment: @icando I don't understand.  Any solution will rely on the optimizing capabilities of the compiler to evaluate f at compile time unless you can represent it as a constexpr in C++11.

Comment: @ChrisHayden, if my templated version is called, then I only assume compiler can do basic inlines.  The technique proposed here requires on more aggressive optimizations that unroll the loop of unknown iterations, e.g. in `printf`, most implementations just `while` loop through the format string.  I can't assume compilers can unroll the `while` loop in this case.

Comment: @ChrisHayden: The author of that post is not using templates, s(he) is using the preprocessor to define a bunch of functions like `void f(char const (&)[1]); void f(char const (&)[2]);`, etc.

Comment: @Jesse Sure, but they are also defining a constructor that accepts a char const *.  If that really is a better match for string literals then I would expect it do be invoked by overload resolution, not the versions that accept the character arrays.  Also, scroll to the bottom where he discusses a template method.

Comment: @icando I still don't see your point.  The best you can do is get the compiler to detect whether you are dealing with a string literal.  Whether it's capable of unrolling the loop is a question of the compilers optimizing capabilities no matter how you perform the detection.  The only exception is if you use preprocessor unrolling, as shown in the link.

Comment: @ChrisHayden: The key point your are missing is in my first comment. It's **template** functions vs. **non-template** functions, your solution works because the foo overloads are *both* **templates**. If you add a **non-template** `foo(const char*)` it will be preferred over the templated versions.

Comment: @Jesse I understand what you're saying, and I admit that I don't know the specific overload resolution rule that causes that to happen.  But, it doesn't really matter, does it?  In this case the OP wants to be able to detect string literals and invoke an appropriate function.  My solution achieves that.

Comment: You're so wrong, it's not even funny. Your "Is string literal" template function will be called for *any* array of characters, string literal or not.

Comment: It will be called for any array of const characters where the number of elements in the array can be determined statically.  You're right in pointing out that the array may not be initialized as a string literal, but I don't see why that matters.  Why would you not want to call the function that offers the best chance for optimization?

Comment: Because the OP clearly specified "String literals only". That is not the same as "Primitive array whose size can be statically determined".