# Why does an empty vector call the value type's default constructor?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, stdvector

Using g++, I observe that creating a vector of size zero calls the vector's parameterized object type's constructor once. It then is deleted. Why does this happen?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class s
{
    public:
    s() { cout << endl << "default s constructor" << endl; }
    ~s() { cout << endl << "default s destructor" << endl; }

};

int main()
{
    vector<s> v(0);
}
```

Output:

default s constructor

default s destructor

Comment: When you upgrade to a C++0x-compliant Standard Library implementation, you'll find that the constructor is not called anymore.  For more, see ["`std::vector`, default construction, C++0x and breaking changes"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759232/stdvector-default-construction-c0x-and-breaking-changes/5759296#5759296)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because you're explicitly passing an initial size, which calls a constructor that has another parameter whose default value is `s()`.  Just leave out the `(0)` (i.e. `std::vector<s> v;`) and it won't happen.

For completeness, the Standard 23.2.4-2 defines the constructor you're calling as:

`explicit vector(size_type n, const T& value =`**`T()`**`,`
                                    `const Allocator& = Allocator());`

**Aside (relevant to C++03 but not C++11)**

Another interesting behavioural aspect of this constructor also raises its head on S.O. periodically: when the initial number of elements requested is > 0, it copy-constructs those elements from the prototypal parameter to the constructor:

- people often put a default constructor that leaves member variables uninitialised, hoping to make `vector(n)` almost as fast as the underlying free store allocation, BUT
- the copy-constructor is still called n times to copy the "garbage" content of the prototypal object into each of the requested elements

This has an obvious performance cost, but can also crash the application *if* the garbage content includes e.g. pointers that the copy-constructor can only assume are valid.  Similarly, it's extremely dangerous to even `push_back` such an uninitialised garbage object - it lacks proper value semantic encapsulation and may be copied as the vector resizes, algorithmic operations like `std::sort()` are performed on the vector etc..

Comment: To clarify, the signature of this constructor is `vector(size_type size, const T& value=T(), const Allocator& = Allocator());`, which means calling as you did, is really calling `vector(0, s(), Allocator())`, thus creating a temporary s object.

Comment: *Just* leaving out the `0` will turn an object definition into a function declaration :) The parenthesis have to be removed, too.

Answer (score 11):

The actual constructor you are calling is (from cplusplus.com):

```
explicit vector ( size_type n, const T& value= T(), const Allocator& = Allocator() );
```

So even though you only specify the size, a new `T` object is created for second parameter, and will therefore also be destroyed at the conclusion of the constructor.