# strange behavior when resize container

Tags: c++, vector

when resizing a vector ,it will call constructor then destruct it.

```
struct CAT
{
    CAT(){cout<<"CAT()"<<endl;}
    CAT(const CAT& c){cout<<"CAT(const CAT& c)"<<endl;};
    ~CAT(){cout<<"~CAT()"<<endl;};
};
int main()
{
    vector<CAT> vc(6);
    cout<<"-----------------"<<endl;
    vc.resize(3);
    cout<<"-----------------"<<endl;

}
```

output:

```
$./m 
CAT()
CAT(const CAT& c)
CAT(const CAT& c)
CAT(const CAT& c)
CAT(const CAT& c)
CAT(const CAT& c)
CAT(const CAT& c)
~CAT()
-----------------
CAT()          //why resize will call constructor?
~CAT()
~CAT()
~CAT()
~CAT()
-----------------
~CAT()
~CAT()
~CAT()
```

I am using ubuntu 13.10 and gcc4.8

Comment: Do you have any optimization turned on? I don't get the same result as you in VS2013.

Comment: @MohammedMajeed, no optimization, here is my compile command g++ -Wall -o m main.cpp . Using "g++ -Wall -O2 -o m main.cpp" will get the same result on my side.

Comment: @herohuyongtao It seem to have created an extra one and so it had to be destructed.

Comment: @camino Your compiler, or the std library that comes with it seem to be buggy. I ran your code on ideone and it worked fine. http://ideone.com/7GJPbA

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488323/why-does-an-empty-vector-call-the-value-types-default-constructor). I don´t think it is a duplicated, but it is close.

Comment: I get the same with gcc-4.8.2 on OS X 10.9. However, Clang yields: `6 x () | 3 x ~() | 3 x ~()`

Comment: @MohammedMajeed Why an extra one?

Comment: @herohuyongtao There is 8 CAT() and 8 ~Cat() as to why check Marks answer

Comment: @herohuyongtao Except that it doesn’t – it destructs exactly as many elements as it constructs.

Comment: @Brett Apparently clang is buggy. See ichramm’s answer for an explanation why the code *must* create these instances. See also [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize).

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Clang provides both overloads. I don't see any bug. GCC's `bits/stl_vector.h` does this as well, if the C++11 dialect is specified.

Comment: @Brett These overloads should exist **only** for C++11. Before that, the compiler has no choice, it has to pick the only available overload, and that always creates a default instance.

Comment: @BrettHale That’s the point: OP is *not* using C++11, they are using C++98. And clang++ in C++98 mode displays the C++11 behaviour. That *is* a bug (albeit not a very bad one). Clang, when called as `clang++ -std=c++98 test.cpp`, should create an executable that produces the same output as OP. It doesn’t.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - You're absolutely right. `clang++ -std=c++98` *doesn't* honour the default argument, whereas `g++` does the right thing for c++98/03 and c++11 respectively. I got it wrong with different standards / compilers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because of the optional argument for `resize`.

This is the implementation I have in GCC 4.8:

```
  void
  resize(size_type __new_size, value_type __x = value_type())
  {
if (__new_size > size())
  insert(end(), __new_size - size(), __x);
else if (__new_size < size())
  _M_erase_at_end(this->_M_impl._M_start + __new_size);
  }
```

Take a closer look to `value_type __x = value_type()`.

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/:

```
void resize (size_type n, value_type val = value_type());
```

Answer (score 5):

Before C++11, `resize` had a defaulted second argument to provide a value for initialising new elements:

```
void resize(size_type sz, T c = T());
```

which explains why you see an extra object created and destroyed.

In a modern library, this is replaced with two overloads

```
void resize(size_type sz);
void resize(size_type sz, const T& c);
```

so you shouldn't see any extra objects unless you explicitly provide one. You should also see default-initialisation, rather than copy-initialisation, during construction.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that your implementation of `vector::resize` creates a temporary default-initialized object even when downsizing, because it uses it to initialize new elements when it's upsizing.

Comment: That's probably the case - otherwise it probably would call `CAT()` 6 times instead of `CAT(const CAT& c)` doing the creation process. It probably does `resize(int x)` when running the constructor.