# Initializing a vector with initial value efficiently

Tags: c++

Given this type for testing:

```
struct Counter
{
    static int count;

    Counter(int)
    {
        count++;
    }

    Counter(const Counter&)
    {
        count++;
    }

    Counter(Counter&&) noexcept
    {

    }
};

int Counter::count = 0;
```

Suppose we have the following:

```
std::vector<Counter> vec(5, 0);
```

According to VS2015, 6 `Counter` objects are created. I know that there are only 5 *permanent* objects. Why doesn't the compiler emplace the objects from the constructor parameters, or move the temporary object into the first position and then copy the rest from it?

Even if the initial size of the vector is set to 0, 1 object is still created.

```
std::vector<Counter> vec(0, 0);
```

This could be important if the size isn't known until run-time and often it is 0 (a no-op) and the type in the container is expensive to copy or construct.

It's often convenient to initialize vectors in one statement, especially if they are class members in the initialization list or constants. How can I do that as efficiently as the following code:

```
std::vector<Counter> vec;
vec.reserve(size);
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    vec.emplace_back(0);
}
```

Which constructs only as many contained objects as there are stored in the vector.

Comment: There should be only 5 objects after the construction of the vector. Add a counter decrement operation to the destructor, and you should get the counting right.

Comment: @DanielStrul I'm interested in the total number of objects constructed *over time*.

Comment: It looks like that this use case is not (yet) covered by the standard. I don't know the reasons but the (count, value) initializer works with const ref values only and not with rvalues.

Comment: Here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488323/why-does-an-empty-vector-call-the-value-types-default-constructor with the unfortunate answer.

Comment: `N+1`is O(N). Why is the one extra construction a problem?

Comment: @AlanStokes I gave an example in the question. Big O can be misleading. If the average elements each time is 4, then this is 25% more peak objects allocated. If the objects are large, this could be enough to fill the CPU cache for example. I'm not saying it is usually a problem, but there are cases where it could be, and the standard library should be well optimized for those cases.

Comment: Isn't it 1 object created and 5 copied? Whereas in the second case there are just five created in place?

Comment: @g24l There are 6 constructor calls, doesn't matter what kind in this case.

Comment: @NeilKirk , why don't they matter ? on might prefer to construct an object and copy that five times.

Comment: @g24l In the case of `std::string` for example, either case allocates dynamic memory, so doesn't really matter.

Comment: @NeilKirk , I see your problem . I would suggest to specify efficiently as "space efficiently" .  But I am certain that the non-copy version would be at least twice as slow. That is why the optimized for time.

Comment: @g24l Why would the non-copy version be at least twice as slow?

Comment: @AlanStokes: Your question demonstrates a fundamental misunderstanding of computer programming. But don't worry, you're not alone: blindly applying big-Oh notation to problems and pretending that one `O(n)` is just as good as another `O(n)` is a common mistake.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit , implies n->inf .

Comment: This idea about avoiding the temporary is all about an extreme case of requiring **convenient notation** for a very border-line marginal optimization. For the usual case of using that temporary to initialize a bunch of vector items, the temporary doesn't matter. Where you want to avoid it you can, by creating a vector with the requisite capacity, just not with the convenient notation. The standard library can't supply convenient notation for every unrealistic use case. It just supplies the basic functionality and support for common usage.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The standard library is used by lots of people so even a small optimization can have a large cumulative effect. I don't think that expecting that creating a vector of 5 objects won't require more than 5 objects to be created is "extreme".

Comment: @NeilKirk you already demonstrated code that will achieve your goal so I don't really see what you are complaining about.  Write a function to encapsulate that code if you want. (the function will return vector by value, and copy elision will ensure no wasted copies).

Comment: @M.M I could and it would take me a few minutes. Doesn't it bother you the standard library that is used by many people for projects big and small, doesn't make such an easy optimization here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply define a function that creates a vector the way that you want.

As a function the initialization code is exception safe.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stddef.h>     // ptrdiff_t
#include <utility>      // std::forward
using namespace std;

struct Counter
{
    static int n_constructor_calls;

    Counter( int )
    {
        ++n_constructor_calls;
    }

    Counter( Counter const& )
    {
        ++n_constructor_calls;
    }

    Counter( Counter&& ) noexcept
    {
        ++n_constructor_calls;
    }
};

int Counter::n_constructor_calls = 0;

//--------------------------------------

using Size = ptrdiff_t;
using Index = Size;

template< class Item, class... Args >
auto make_vector( Size const n, Args&&... args )
    -> vector<Item>
{
    vector<Item>    result;
    result.reserve( n );
    for( Index i = 0; i < n; ++i )
    {
        result.emplace_back( forward<Args>( args )... );
    }
    return result;
}

auto main() -> int
{
    auto vec = make_vector<Counter>( 5, 42 );
    cout << Counter::n_constructor_calls << " constructor calls.\n";
}
```

(This outputs “5 constructor calls.”)

You essentially ask, why isn't the `vector` constructor defined to do this,

> **”** Why doesn't the compiler emplace the objects from the constructor parameters, or move the temporary object into the first position and then copy the rest from it?

One reason is that this constructor was defined before move semantics was introduced in C++11.

Introducing additional constructors (which changes overload behavior), or changing the behavior of an existing constructor, is expensive with respect to the existing C++ code base, which is very large.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is efficient, **based on your definition**.

Testing the different versions;

```
Copies: 100000005 , Construct: 1, Equal copies 0
real    0m0.075s
user    0m0.073s
sys 0m0.002s
```

and with emplace_back:

```
Copies: 0 , Construct: 100000005, Equal copies 0
real    0m0.195s
user    0m0.191s
sys 0m0.004s
```

you may mean it is space efficient. However, that is a choice based on use case, and seems compiler designers prefer speed.

Here is the code ( I track also equal )

```
struct Counter
{
static int count_ctor;
static int count_copy;
static int count_equal;

Counter(int){count_ctor++;}    
Counter(const Counter&){count_copy++;}    
Counter(Counter&&) noexcept{}
Counter & operator=(Counter const &){ count_equal++ ;}
};

int Counter::count_copy = 0;
int Counter::count_ctor = 0;
int Counter::count_equal = 0;

int main(void)
{
  int size(100000005);

#ifdef EMPLACE
  std::vector<Counter> v;
  v.reserve(size);
  for(int i = size; i>0 ; --i){ v.emplace_back(0);}
#else
  std::vector<Counter> v(size,0);
#endif    
  std::printf("Copies: %d , Construct: %d, Equal copies %d",Counter::count_copy, Counter::count_ctor, Counter::count_equal);
  return 0;
}
```

*compile with g++ -DEMPLACE --std=c++11 -O3* or without EMPLACE to get the desired binary.

**SECOND TEST**

In order to rebute the assumptions made by the OP , the following test has been made:

1. Creation of many small vectors created within multiple larger classes
2. All objects created either with the default construct-copy policy or by calling an emplace wrapper function.

We produced two binaries with

```
g++ -DEMPLACE --std=c++11 -O3 copyc.cpp -o copyc && g++ --std=c++11 -O3 copyc.cpp -o copyc_copy
```

and in order to avoid any of the two having preferential treatement from the OS , we set a standard pause of 10s in between them, and we launch with the system at idle.

An exemplary run is below.

```
export K=10192 ; time ./copyc_copy $K ; sleep 10; time ./copyc $K
Copies: 10192 , Construct: 1, Equal copies 0
real    0m2.888s
user    0m0.666s
sys 0m2.219s
Copies: 0 , Construct: 10192, Equal copies 0
real    0m3.376s
user    0m1.105s
sys 0m2.270s
```

I've run this in multiple cases , and also in reverse

```
Copies: 0 , Construct: 10192, Equal copies 0
real    0m3.154s
user    0m0.886s
sys 0m2.267s
Copies: 10192 , Construct: 1, Equal copies 0
real    0m2.573s
user    0m0.531s
sys 0m2.025s
```

That being said this is an incoclusive test, but having spent this match time on this, I bet the compiler designers did more , and all from gnu to clang and VS decided to implement a construct-copy policy. I am certain they had other reasons as well.

The code for the second test is below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

template<typename T> static std::vector<T> get5()
{
std::vector<T> s;
s.reserve(5);
for(int i=5; i!=0 ;--i)
{
s.emplace_back(T());
}
return s;
}

struct test_struct
{
    volatile int internals[255];
};

struct test_create
{
std::vector<test_struct> s;
test_create() : s(5){}
};

struct test_emplace
{
std::vector<test_struct> s;
test_emplace() : s(get5<test_struct>()){}
};


struct Counter
{
static int count_ctor;
static int count_copy;
static int count_equal;

#ifdef EMPLACE
test_emplace t[100];
#else
test_create t[100];
#endif

Counter(int)
{
count_ctor++;
}

Counter(const Counter&)
{
count_copy++;
}

Counter(Counter&&) noexcept
{

}
Counter & operator=(Counter const &){ count_equal++ ;}
};

int Counter::count_copy = 0;
int Counter::count_ctor = 0;
int Counter::count_equal = 0;

int main(int arg, char const * argv[])
{
int size(std::atoi(argv[1]));

#ifdef EMPLACE
std::vector<Counter> v;
v.reserve(size);
for(int i = size; i>0 ; --i)
{
    v.emplace_back(0);
}
#else
std::vector<Counter> v(size,0);
#endif

std::printf("Copies: %d , Construct: %d, Equal copies %d",Counter::count_copy, Counter::count_ctor, Counter::count_equal);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: The one with `emplace_back` performs the most copies?

Comment: What is the type you used in the container?

Comment: @NeilKirk , I used your code , try it out yourself, and test a big size , and yes it is reserved before to the appropriate size, before the emplace_back loop.

Comment: You need to run it with an object that is expensive to construct to be representative of my use case.

Comment: @NeilKirk , I would say an object which is expensive to copy , but still one has to make a choice.

Comment: The object in your example is not expensive to copy therefore the results mean nothing.

Comment: @NeilKirk , indeed , that is what is expected. Usually objects are more expensive to construct, than to copy. But still , that is an optimization choice.

Comment: What is an optimization choice? Apart from corner cases, the code with the least constructions will be faster and use less memory.

Comment: @NeilKirk , "least constructions" more "copying" is what is done here.

Comment: I am considering a copy constructor and non-copy constructor to count as 1 construction.

Comment: @NeilKirk , you are considering it that way , the commands to do that are not one and the same . Look at the assembly generated by the compiler.

Comment: This isn't going anywhere. You need to run with a representative example to compare the techniques.

Comment: @NeilKirk you're the one claiming that there is a performance issue so the onus is on you to produce a benchmark proving that there actually is such an issue

Comment: @M.M It is a general question. I know I can contrive a example which shows the performance issue, so what is the point? I just wondered if there is a reason why the standard is needlessly inefficient in this case.

Comment: @NeilKirk it is quite the opposite, the standard says nothing to accommodate both cases, the one that you know that you can fabricate, and the one above.

Comment: @g24l I'm sorry but I am not following you any more. A test with a dummy class that doesn't need to copy anything doesn't show any relevant performance results. Also my use case is where many small vectors are created.