# C++11 make_pair with specified template parameters doesn't compile

Tags: c++, templates, g++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I was just playing around with g++ 4.7 (one of the later snapshots) with -std=c++11 enabled. I tried to compile some of my existing code base and one case that failed somewhat confuses me.

I would appreciate if someone can explain what is going on.

Here's the code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main ( )
{
    std::string s = "abc";

    // 1 ok
    std::pair < std::string, int > a = std::make_pair ( s, 7 );

    // 2 error on the next line
    std::pair < std::string, int > b = std::make_pair < std::string, int > ( s, 7 );

    // 3 ok
    std::pair < std::string, int > d = std::pair < std::string, int > ( s, 7 );

    return 0;
}
```

I understand that make_pair is *meant* to be used as the (1) case (if I specify the types, then I might as well use (3)), but I don't understand why it's failing in this case.

The exact error is:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
    test.cpp:11:83: error: no matching function for call to ‘make_pair(std::string&, int)’
    test.cpp:11:83: note: candidate is:
    In file included from /gcc4.7/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/utility:72:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
    /gcc4.7/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/bits/stl_pair.h:274:5:
note: template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr std::pair<typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T1>::__type, typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T2>::__type> std::make_pair(_T1&&, _T2&&)
    /gcc4.7/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/bits/stl_pair.h:274:5:
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
    test.cpp:11:83: note:   cannot convert ‘s’ (type ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’) to type ‘std::basic_string<char>&&’
```

Again, the question here is just "what's going on?" I know that I can fix the problem by removing the template specification, but I just want to know what's failing here under the covers.

- g++ 4.4 compiles this code with no problems.
- Removing -std=c++11 also compiles with code with no problems.

Comment: An excellent question.  Yet another example of a subtle breaking change in C++11, similar to [the breaking change in `std::vector` construction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759232/stdvector-default-construction-c11-and-breaking-changes).  At least this one yields a compiler error and not a silent change in semantics.

Comment: If I have an integer variable i. I want to make pair with i and another object. How exactly should I call makepair. 1) make_pair<*i, obj> 2) int&& j = i; make_pair<j, obj>? Both are not working. Whats the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

This is not how `std::make_pair` is intended to be used; you are not supposed to explicitly specify the template arguments.

The C++11 `std::make_pair` takes two arguments, of type `T&&` and `U&&`, where `T` and `U` are template type parameters.  Effectively, it looks like this (ignoring the return type):

```
template <typename T, typename U>
[return type] make_pair(T&& argT, U&& argU);
```

When you call `std::make_pair` and explicitly specify the template type arguments, no argument deduction takes place.  Instead, the type arguments are substituted directly into the template declaration, yielding:

```
[return type] make_pair(std::string&& argT, int&& argU);
```

Note that both of these parameter types are rvalue references.  Thus, they can only bind to rvalues.  This isn't a problem for the second argument that you pass, `7`, because that is an rvalue expression.  `s`, however, is an lvalue expression (it isn't a temporary and it isn't being moved).  This means the function template is not a match for your arguments, which is why you get the error.

So, why does it work when you don't explicitly specify what `T` and `U` are in the template argument list?  In short, rvalue reference parameters are special in templates.  Due in part to a language feature called [reference collapsing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Reference_collapsing), an rvalue reference parameter of type `A&&`, where `A` is a template type parameter, can bind to any kind of `A`.

It doesn't matter whether the `A` is an lvalue, an rvalue, const-qualified, volatile-qualified, or unqualified, an `A&&` can bind to that object (again, if and only if `A` is itself a template parameter).

In your example, we make the call:

```
make_pair(s, 7)
```

Here, `s` is an lvalue of type `std::string` and `7` is an rvalue of type `int`.  Since you do not specify the template arguments for the function template, template argument deduction is performed to figure out what the arguments are.

To bind `s`, an lvalue, to `T&&`, the compiler deduces `T` to be `std::string&`, yielding an argument of type `std::string& &&`.  There are no references to references, though, so this "double reference" collapses to become `std::string&`.  `s` is a match.

It's simple to bind `7` to `U&&`: the compiler can deduce `U` to be `int`, yielding a parameter of type `int&&`, which binds successfully to `7` because it is an rvalue.

There are lots of subtleties with these new language features, but if you follow one simple rule, it's pretty easy:

> If a template argument can be deduced from the function arguments, let it be deduced.  Don't explicitly provide the argument unless you absolutely must.
>
> Let the compiler do the hard work, and 99.9% of the time it'll be exactly what you wanted anyway.  When it isn't what you wanted, you'll usually get a compilation error which is easy to identify and fix.

Comment: @James - is that "one simple rule" from another article or answer I should read?

Comment: @MichaelBurr:  Nah, I just made that up.  :-)  So, I hope it's true!  I think it's true... that rule works for me pretty much all the time.

Comment: @James: thanks. The 'quote box' around it made me think it might have been something originally written elsewhere. This answer was really informative, and I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something somewhere else.

Comment: Does this apply to tuples as well?

Comment: OP already knows how make_pair is supposed to be used, he was just looking for more insight into the internals of the error. You don't need to scold him.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis If I have an integer variable i. I want to make pair with i and another object. How exactly should I call makepair. 1) make_pair<*i, obj> 2) int&& j = i; make_pair<j, obj>? Both are not working. Whats the correct way to do it?