# Can I compile Google's protobuf under Visual Studio 11?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, visual-studio-2012

Visual studio 11 (beta) uses the new C++11 standard, which seems to break protobuf. Where I'm stuck at the moment is the way that the C++11 standard defines `make_pair`. The problem is defined well [in this StackOverflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641960/c11-make-pair-with-specified-template-parameters-doesnt-compile) and is defined as [by design](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/691756/std-make-pair-error-in-vc11) by Microsoft.

I'm trying to compile a "small, but complex" project using Visual Studio 2011 Beta that includes protobuf. Is there a way to get this to work with VS11 (patch, compiler setting, ...), or do I have to "downgrade" to VS2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's [issue 379](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/issues/detail?id=379). The report suggests a workaround to replace `make_pair<string, string>` with `pair<string, string>` at the two problem locations in *command_line_interface.cc*.

A tempting solution is to remove the template arguments entirely since they're not needed. However, that would cause a regression of [issue 166](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/issues/detail?id=166), which prompted the addition of the template arguments to work around a problem with Sun compilers.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Somehow I missed that in my google search ... didn't seem to show up. Wrong keywords, I guess.