# cannot convert argument 1 from int to int && error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Today I wanted to try to bring my project from visual c++ 2010 to visual c++ 2013.

I get this error in visual c++ 2013 which I did not get when compiling with 2010 version.

```
//somewhere in the SimpleObject_list class
std::unordered_map<std::string, SimpleObject *> Object_list; 


//method which is giving me the error
void SimpleObject_list::Add(const char *Object_name, SimpleObject * Object_pointer){
    cout << "SimpleObject listed as: " << Object_name << endl;
    Object_list.insert(std::make_pair<std::string,SimpleObject *>(Object_name, Object_pointer));
}
```

the error is:

```
error C2664: 'std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,SimpleObject *> std::make_pair<std::string,SimpleObject*>(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'SimpleObject *' to 'SimpleObject *&&'
```

what am I doing wrong? Why I did not get any error in vc++ 2010?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change

```
Object_list.insert(std::make_pair<std::string,SimpleObject *>(Object_name, Object_pointer));
```

to

```
Object_list.insert(std::make_pair(Object_name, Object_pointer));
```

Comment: For a better description why this is required look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641960/c11-make-pair-with-specified-template-parameters-doesnt-compile

Comment: @Marco see my comment added a few seconds before your last comment.