# std::make_pair, c++11 and explicit template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, c++03

Reedited: first of all, this is just a matter of curiosity, I do know, that std::pair or lots of other solutions could eradicate this issue.

Can you tell me, what is exactly behind of this following problem? This code is a simple example working on c++03 and fails on c++11.

```
    std::pair<int*,int**> getsth(int* param)
    {
        return std::make_pair<int*,int**>(param, 0);
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        int* a = new int(1);
        std::pair<int*,int**> par = getsth(a);
        std::cout << *par.first;
        return 0;
    }
```

I do know how to fix it to be compatible with both standards here, but it is annyoing me, that I don't know, what is exactly behind make_pair in this case.

Thanks!

edited: a compile error message from Coliru:

```
main.cpp: In function 'std::pair<int*, int**> getsth(int*)':
main.cpp:8:47: error: no matching function for call to 'make_pair(int*&, int)'
     return std::make_pair<int*,int**>(param, 0);
                                               ^
main.cpp:8:47: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/ios:40,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_pair.h:276:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr std::pair<typename std::__decay_and_strip<_Tp>::__type, typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T2>::__type> std::make_pair(_T1&&, _T2&&)
     make_pair(_T1&& __x, _T2&& __y)
     ^
/usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_pair.h:276:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:8:47: note:   cannot convert 'param' (type 'int*') to type 'int*&&'
     return std::make_pair<int*,int**>(param, 0);
                                               ^
main.cpp:9:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
```

Comment: Please show your compile error, assuming there is one

Comment: Writing `std::make_pair<int*,int**>(param, 0)` is [totally pointless](http://www.advogato.org/person/redi/diary/239.html), the whole point of `make_pair` is to deduce the argument types. If you don't want the types to be deduced then just say `std::pair<int*,int**>(param, 0)` and save yourself typing five redundant characters.

Comment: Just going to point out `return {param, 0};`

Comment: @chris Not going to work in 03.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rvalue references happened. Where `std::make_pair` in C++03 has the signature

```
template< class T1, class T2 >
std::pair<T1,T2> make_pair( T1 t, T2 u );
```

In C++11, it has

```
template< class T1, class T2 >
std::pair<V1,V2> make_pair( T1&& t, T2&& u );
```

`V1` and `V2` are (usually) `std::decay<T1|T2>::type`. C++14 adds `constexpr`, but that does concern us here.

This means that the explicit function template specialization `std::make_pair<int*, int**>` accepted, in C++03, parameters of type `int*` and `int**`, while the new one in C++11 accepts `int*&&` and `int**&&`.

Binding `0` to `int**&&` is not a problem, but `param` is an lvalue and cannot be bound to an rvalue reference to `int*`. And that is why your code explodes in C++11.

For this reason,

```
return std::make_pair<int*&, int**>(param, 0);
```

works with both C++03 and C++11 -- `param` can be bound to `int*&`, and the resulting `std::pair<int*&, int**>` can be converted to the `std::pair<int*, int**>` that the function wants to return in both revisions.

That is rather ugly, though, and `std::make_pair` is not really meant to be used this way. As @T.C. points out in the comments, if you know the types the `std::pair` should have, just use

```
return std::pair<int*, int**>(param, 0);
```

Comment: `std::pair<int*, int**>(param, 0)`. `make_pair` is never meant to be used with explicit template arguments.

Comment: Thanks, this was somewhat my guess. But doesn't have it a normal <typename A, typename B> definition as well?

Comment: @newhouse I think he meant that the answer should mention this, and I agree -- it will still be here in a year, and it's not just us who're potentially going to read it.

Comment: @newhouse, why do you think T.C. is being a smartass? Why do you think `return std::pair<int*, int**>(param, 0)` is not compatible with the return type?

Comment: @JonathanWakely
I misread that one, yeah, that is ok.

Comment: Yet still, this was just a question of curiosity and I just wanted to know, what was the exact problem behind this in c++11, because it worked in c++03. And we got an answer below, so...

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the template parameters of make_pair.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641960/c11-make-pair-with-specified-template-parameters-doesnt-compile) is more info on why.

Also, you should pass `nullptr` to `make_pair`, not 0.

Comment: I think the problem is it also needs to be C++03 compliant, which I don't know if it would be, without explicit parameters.

Comment: You missed the part "C++03 compilant", as well as the fact, that I have an exact return type, so if I remove the template parameter definition of make_pair, it won't compile either.

Comment: @newhouse it would, if you didn't use 0 as a pointer. There's no `nullptr` in C++03, but you can still hardtype it `reinterpret_cast<int**>(0)`.

Comment: @GiulioFranco `s/reinterpret/static/`.

Comment: @T.C. does it have any importance when dealing with nulls?

Comment: @GiulioFranco `static_cast` is guaranteed to work. `reinterpret_cast` isn't.

Comment: @GiulioFranco Yeah, that one was out of scope, because the original code, where I got this had some other make_pairs with NULLs and this would have been a misery. I used &*param at make_pair to create and rvalue :)