# std::pair with reference to unique pointer

Tags: c++

Currently using C++20, GCC 11.1.0

I'm trying to create a class method that returns a `std::pair` of `uint32_t` and a reference to a unique pointer. The unique pointer comes from a vector of unique pointers stored as a variable in the class. However, it keeps saying:

```
error: could not convert ‘std::make_pair(_T1&&, _T2&&) [with _T1 = unsigned int; _T2 = std::unique_ptr<Panel>&; typename std::__strip_reference_wrapper<typename std::decay<_Tp2>::type>::__type = std::unique_ptr<Panel>; typename std::decay<_Tp2>::type = std::decay<std::unique_ptr<Panel>&>::type; typename std::__strip_reference_wrapper<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type>::__type = unsigned int; typename std::decay<_Tp>::type = unsigned int]((* &((Screen*)this)->Screen::panels.std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Panel> >::emplace_back<>()))’ from ‘pair<[...],std::unique_ptr<Panel>>’ to ‘pair<[...],std::unique_ptr<Panel>&>’
   67 |         return std::make_pair<PanelID, Panel_Ptr&>(
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
      |                                                   |
      |                                                   pair<[...],std::unique_ptr<Panel>>
   68 |             std::move(panelID), panels.emplace_back());
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

```
class Screen
{
private:
    using PanelID = uint32_t;
    using Panel_Ptr = std::unique_ptr<Panel>;
    std::vector<Panel_Ptr> panels {};

public:
    std::pair<PanelID, Panel_Ptr&> foo()
    {
        PanelID panelID {static_cast<PanelID>(panels.size())};
        return std::make_pair<PanelID, Panel_Ptr&>(
            std::move(panelID), panels.emplace_back());
    }
};
```

Comment: Possibly related: [make_pair with specified template parameters doesn't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641960/) Does it work if you get rid of the explicit template parameters on `make_pair()` (and also get rid of the unnecessary `std::move()`)? `return std::make_pair(panelID, panels.emplace_back());`

Comment: No, it still gives the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::make_pair()` will automatically decay any references given to it to their value types.

> The deduced types `V1` and `V2` are `std::decay<T1>::type` and `std::decay<T2>::type` (the usual type transformations applied to arguments of functions passed by value) **unless application of `std::decay` results in `std::reference_wrapper<X>`** for some type `X`, in which case the deduced type is `X&`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair

Remove your explicit instantiation of the type parameters of `std::make_pair()` and wrap the `emplace_back()` call with `std::ref`:

```
return std::make_pair(
    std::move(panelID), 
    std::ref(panels.emplace_back())
);
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly make the `std::pair`:

```
return std::pair<PanelID, Panel_Ptr&>(
    std::move(panelID), 
    panels.emplace_back()
);
```

Finally, to note on your code, you are calling `std::move()` on your `PanelID` type even though it is just an integer. `std::move()` is useless in that scenario, so removing it entirely would make your code clearer.

Though, putting the generation of `panelID` on a separate statement is still necessary due to the unspecified order of evaluation of arguments passed to functions. Good awareness of this fact.

Comment: "*putting it on a separate line is still necessary due to the unspecified order of evaluation of arguments passed to functions*" - the compiler ignores whitespace between statements, arguments, etc, so putting the arguments on separate lines makes no difference whatsoever to the compiler, it only enhances readability for humans.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I believe you misread what I stated there. By line I meant a statement, and they had separated their two statements by line so I said it by line. I will alter the wording to make it more clear. But my point still stands, inside a function call like `foo(a(), b(), c())`, the order that each argument is evaluated is unspecified (ie., a, b, or c can be called in any order).

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order
"Order of evaluation of any part of any expression, including *order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified*"