# Error inserting a function as value into a std::map

Tags: c++, stdmap, std-function, lvalue

I am trying to create a `std::map` that has an integer as the key and a function as the value. When I try to insert a value, either via `=` or `insert()`, I get the following error:

> Error C2207   'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::second': a member of a class template cannot acquire a function type

Here is the sample code:

```
std::map<int, std::function<void()>> myMap;
myMap[0] = [] {std::cout << "zero\n"; };
myMap.insert(std::make_pair<int, std::function<void()> >(0, [] {std::cout << "zero\n";} ) )
```

Why can't I do this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Apart from anything else you appear to have a typo: `std::function<void>()` --> `std::function<void()>` in the declaration of `myMap`.

Comment: @273K ???????????

Comment: @273K They can use whatever they want. The system is clever, when I type `@` it suggests `πάνταῥεῖ` (only), because they're the only commenter here with unprintable characters in the name. On the other hand, when I do `@H` (cyrillic Н on a cyrillic keyboard), I don't get any suggestion, because you're not supposed to `@` the OP.

Comment: @НиколаХилендаров Please undo your last edit.  Editing the question in a way that renders existing comments/answers obsolete is counterproductive.

Comment: (1) add a semicolon at the end of the 3rd line. (2) insert into a different key position. (3) use emplace `myMap.emplace(1, [] {std::cout << "xero\n";}) ;`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You are not completely right. НиколаХилендаров is suggested after his comment although he is the OP. πάνταῥεῖ is suggested too. But your nickname is not suggested until H is typed. The single @ seems to start with competition of non ASCII nicknames only.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/ojWrq6M91).

Comment: It is a [mistake to explicitly specify the template parameters of `std::make_pair()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641960/), always let it deduce the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

A lambda is not a std::function, so you need to do a bit more work.
Usually I have a class with a map as member and a function template that allows to add lambda. Here is some code without such a wrapper.

Note that initializing at construction is by far the easiest way to do it. Then the constructor of std::function<void()> is called with the lambda (which is fine).

```
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

template<typename fn_t>
auto to_fn(fn_t&& fn)
{
    return std::function<void()>{fn};
}


int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::function<void()>> map
    {
        { 0, [] { std::cout << "0\n"; }}
    };

    // map.insert(1, []{ std::cout << "1\n"; }); a lambda is not a function

    map.insert({ 1, std::function<void()>{ [] { std::cout << "1\n"; } } });
    map.insert({ 2, to_fn([] { std::cout << "2\n"; }) });


    map[2]();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but for some reason this is not working for me. I am getting this error 
"Error C2207 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::second': a member of a class template cannot acquire a function type"
I guess it might be compiler specific.

Comment: Could be clang/gcc and msvc I tested don't seem to have that problem. 
e.g. clang : https://godbolt.org/z/v6zbhj5jr