# How many times std::vector::resize should default-construct new elements?

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

Our team just ran into the same issue described here http://forums.codeguru.com/archive/index.php/t-514404.html, i.e. calling `some_vec.resize(new_size)`, where `N = new_size - some_vec.size()` with N >= 2, and VC10 default-constructed all N new elements, whereas GCC default constructed a single element, as the *prototype* element, to copy-construct it N times for the new elements.

Since this is a vector of uuid, where the default-constructor randomly initializes each new instance, we ended up with N times the same uuid with GCC and N different uuids with VC. That was enough to wreak havoc in our test suite on one platform but not another, and was no fun to find.

My question is thus: who is right? VC or GCC? Or is this one of those beloved corners of C++ that's unspecified? TIA, --DD

Comment: The standard has changed. Here is a similar question [std::vector, default construction, C++11 and breaking changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759232/stdvector-default-construction-c11-and-breaking-changes)

Comment: It should be noted that your class is a bit "weird": Basically, you have the situation where for `T x; T y;` you have `x != y`. This warrants a lot of extra care, and explicit documentation...

Comment: Randomization on construction is a bad thing, you can see it in your example. Most code assumes that all default constructed objects are equal. To solve these problems you should have a randomizing function. Or a factory that creates randomized objects.

Comment: Thank you all for the lightning fast answers. Indeed we are in C++03 on GCC, and leave VC10 in its C++11 default mode. Yes, our uid class could have default-constructed to a null/zero uid, but I was not there in september 2003 when it was introduced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I bet if you compile GCC with `-std=c++0x`, you'll get the same result as with MSVC, that is, the N default constructions. This has changed in C++11, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize). There are now two overloads, one with just the new size that default constructs the new elements, and another that takes a "prototype" parameter to copy-construct every new element from.

Now, to get consistent results no matter what mode you compile in, just use

```
v.resize(new_size, T());
```

Background info: The change was necessary, since there are now types that can be movable, but not copyable (like `std::unique_ptr`). The old signature demanded copyability. Now the first template parameter to standard container types is only required to be copyable, if you use operations that require a copy.